# Requests for django in the case of a foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have two tables, Author and Book, Each book is written by a mutliple author, by against an author can create a (one) book, I want to get the book list created by a single author. 
In my template, I would view the authors who have written one book

my models.py

```
class Book(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User,related_name='user')
        name = models.CharField(default=0)
        def __unicode__(self):
                return u'%s' % self.user

class author(models.Model):
        name_auth = models.CharField(max_length=256)
        Book = models.ForeignKey(compte)
        def __unicode__(self):
                return u'%s' % (self.name_auth)
```

my view.py

```
Book1 =Book.objects.filter(user=request.user).values()
Book1_id= Book1.id
author = Author.objects.filter(pk=Book1_id).values
reponse[author]=author
```

my template

```
 {% for t in author %}
                            <td>{{ t.name }}</td>

        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: I recommend you read through and practice the basics in [the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/) .  What I find lacking in your question is a question.  It looks more like "debug my code please".

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation, but I am a beginner and I have not found an answer to my problem and that is the reason to post this message here

Comment: That's why it's helpful to work yourself through the tutorial.  It will make clear the failings of your code.  Trust me.

Comment: I just re-read the tutorial but it did not help me, that's the stuff I did before posting my problem in this forum !!!!

Comment: Try [this one](https://realpython.com/learn/start-django/)

Answer (score 0):

The logic in your models is incorrect given your statement...

> "A book can have multiple authors"

You need to use a [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield) to represent the authors of a book:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.get_full_name()

class Book(models.Model):
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


# views

from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

def book_detail(request, book_id):
    book = get_object_or_404(Book, id=book_id).prefetch_related('authors')

    return render(request, 'book_detail.html', {'book': book})


# book_detail.html

{% for author in book.authors.all %}
    {{ author }}
{% endfor %}
```